# criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()) with Hibernate produces unexpected result

Tags: database, hibernate, criteria, projection

We are using hibernate 3.3 for our application and facing this weired problem in which

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(table.class);
```

`criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());` returns 4 rows, 3 having values '0' and 1 with correct value.

Because of this issue `criteria.uniqueResult();` throws an exception saying `org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 4`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The worst part is that we are facing the same issue with HQL. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reason myself!

There are multiple classes (3 exactly) which are inheriting the table we are firing this query on("table"). So, because of this our query gets fired to all 4 tables.

Resolved a lot of our problems.

Wowww!!! What a relief it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int count = getSession().createCriteria(table.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
    .criteria.uniqueResult<int>();
```